# Python: Comparing elements in a list and printing elements with the biggest match count

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have just started learning python.

I'm trying to compare elements in the list. For example I have a list:

```
list = [['red', 'blue', 'black'], ['red', 'blue', ' white'], ['red', 'pink']]
```

Now, how can I compare element 0: `['red','blue','black']` with the rest of elements in the list and print those elements with the biggest count of matches, like the most matching element is `['red', 'blue', ' white']` next  `['red', 'pink']`

**Update:**

At this point I managed to do something like this:

```
mylist = [set(item) for item in list]
for i, item in enumerate(mylist):
    for i1 in xrange(i + 1, len(mylist)):
        for val in (item & mylist[i1]):
            print "Index {} matched with index {} for value
{}".format(i,i1,val)
            if i == 0:
                print list[(i1)]
```

Output:

```
Index 0 matched with index 1 for value "Red"
['red', 'blue', ' white']
Index 0 matched with index 1 for value "Blue"
['red', 'blue', ' white']
...
```

I have found a solution:
[Python: Compare elements in a list to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958227/python-compare-elements-in-a-list-to-each-other).

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? Explain what part of your implementation is giving you difficulties.

Comment: Try using counter - https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects

Comment: Or rather [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Comment: Matching just in content or in position too?

Comment: just in content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort a list by a length of sets of intersections:

```
key = ['red', 'blue', 'black']
l = [['red', 'pink'], ['red', 'blue', ' white'], ['red', 'blue', 'black']]
sorted_by_matching = sorted(l, key=lambda x: -len(set(x) & set(key)))

print(sorted_by_matching)
>> [['red', 'blue', 'black'], ['red', 'blue', ' white'], ['red', 'pink']]
```

Comment: Thanks, its very simple solution to my probelm, but i have questions.
How can i print for example ony 2 out of 3 answers?
How can i change the way that is printed, for example printed one answer under another?

Comment: @user7375796 You can get a [slice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/4229825) of the list. If you want to get first n elements, just do `l[:n]`. For example, first 2 element: `l[:2]`, which are `[['red', 'blue', 'black'], ['red', 'blue', ' white']` in this case.