# Simple program to append *** to a line in a list of users

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a simple program that will read a list of users in my AD group and put "***" after a name if its new. It doesnt seem to be working write so I am just wondering where I am going wrong. here is what I have:

```
list1 = open('testlist.txt', 'r')

for i in list1:
   print(i, end=' ')


list2 = open('NewUserList.txt', 'r+')

for ii in list2:
   if ii not in list1:
      list2.write(ii.strip("\n")+" ***\n")
```

Example of list1:

```
Mike Smith
John Smith
Tom Smith
```

Here is an example of what I am getting in list2 when its done:

```
Mike Smith
John Smith
Tom Smith
Jerry Smith
Mike Smith ***
John Smith ***
Tom Smith ***
Jerry Smith ***
```

Obviously this is showing that existing users are new users along with the new user.... What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this question, might solve your issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603282/how-to-compare-each-item-in-a-list-with-the-rest-only-once

Comment: What's in list2/NewUserList originally?

Comment: You need to copy each line to a new file, if you append text to the end of an existing line you will overwrite the next one

Comment: @Rome_Leader the NewUserList has the new list of names with no duplicates and no ***.

Comment: @cdarke I am not sure how to do that :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in list1:
```

`list` yields the lines, but doesn't store them. You have to keep the values yourself:

```
s = set()

with open('testlist.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
        s.add(line)
```

Comment: I am getting this: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\readlist.py", line 11, in <module>
    if ii not in f:
TypeError: argument of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' is not iterable`

Comment: We're storing the seen names in the set `s`.  Check `if ii not in s:`

Comment: That worked, I was still using f (list1) for my IF statement. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`list1` is an iterator that ends on the first loop.

Use the `split` method:

```
list1 = open('testlist.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')
```

and you'll find much more peace.

Comment: I am getting this back:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\readlist.py", line 1, in <module>
    list1 = open('testlist.txt', 'r').split('\n')
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: Same thing, it appends every name in the list with " ***"