# comparing every element in a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop

i want to compare every element of a list and see if there is an element which occurs more than once
my code doesn't function, i want to return False if there is one element that occurs more than once, True if all elements are different.
i have tried this so far:

```
def diffElements(liste):
   i = 0
   j = 1
   while i < len(liste):
       if liste[i] == liste[j]:
           return False
       j += 1
       if j == len(liste) - 1:
        print("Jj: " + str(j))
           i += 1
           j = i + 1
```

Comment: This is not valid Python code (syntax error: indentation).

Comment: Looks like you've got an indentation error on the line you're using to print - that could be causing trouble.

Comment: Create a set from the list and return if their sizes are different.

Comment: You have not explained *what* the problem is, which makes it hard to say *how* to fix it.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603282/how-to-compare-each-item-in-a-list-with-the-rest-only-once) is a similar post

Comment: Note that your function *never*, under any circumstances, returns `True`.

Answer (score 4):

Use a set to detect duplicates:

```
def diffElements(liste):
    return len(set(liste)) != len(liste)
```